# Which is the better way to write typing hint after Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

In Python 3.7 with [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/), there are two ways to write typing hint:

```
from typing import List

def merge(xs: List[int], ys: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    return xs + ys
```

or

```
def merge(xs: list[int], ys: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    return xs + ys
```

Both seem works the same. Which is the recommended one?

**EDIT**: The second way already supported in PyCharm
[image]

Comment: Considering that `list[int]` throws a `'type' object is not subscriptable` exception, I'd say that the top one is recommended.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Please use Python 3.7

Comment: Does this actually work in python 3.7? The PEP never mentions that this idea got approved or implemented. Either way, compatibility with 3.5 and 3.6 is still a reason to use the `typing` variant.

Comment: I'd go with `typing` as it's vastly more compatible - the import is largely ignored in production settings so having an additional line or two in your code is well worth the backwards compatibility.